# effective debugging my QGIS c++ plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, c++

For debugging my QGIS-plugins in Visual Studio 2008 I have to start QGIS and attach the process (with `Ctrl-P`) to my debugger in VS. This is because the plugin is a dll and has to be loaded during QGIS start.

Is there an ability to have QGIS opened all the time and load the plugin.dll new if needed?